# Cannot allocate memory for activeadmin in ubuntu 14.04 with DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory, bundle, digital-ocean

I am facing below error while doing `bundle install` using Ubuntu 14.04 with `DigitalOcean`

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git' "/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/bundler/git/activeadmin-c24fcef949b2f1bbdf6b5a17650dcd86d73f2528" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (2/3): Errno::ENOMEM Cannot allocate memory - git clone 'git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git' "/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/bundler/git/activeadmin-c24fcef949b2f1bbdf6b5a17650dcd86d73f2528" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet
Retrying git clone 'git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git' "/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/bundler/git/activeadmin-c24fcef949b2f1bbdf6b5a17650dcd86d73f2528" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet due to error (3/3): Errno::ENOMEM Cannot allocate memory - git clone 'git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git' "/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/bundler/git/activeadmin-c24fcef949b2f1bbdf6b5a17650dcd86d73f2528" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler
troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb:114:in ``': Cannot allocate memory - git clone 'git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git' "/home/sachin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/cache/bundler/git/activeadmin-c24fcef949b2f1bbdf6b5a17650dcd86d73f2528" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

Would anybody know of a solution?

Comment: how much memory on your droplet?

Comment: Thanks. I do have 512MB in my droplet. I have resolved it with add swap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have found solution that I do need some more memory for bundle install. That's why I have created swap in harddisk with 512MB memory and it is working fine for me.

You can create swap from [here.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)